# Populating a malloc array when reading from a file

Tags: c, file, malloc

```
// Trying to store the the data from a text file into an array
  char *buff(const char *path){
    int end = 0;
    char * buf;
    int f_write = open(path,O_RDONLY);
    end = lseek(f_write,0,SEEK_END);
    buf =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(end+1));
    read(f_write,buf,end+1);
    close(f_write);
    buf[end+1]= '\0';
    printf("%s\n",buf);//Prints empty line because buf has not been populated
    return buf;
 }
```

I am trying to create a function that opens a file then I use lseek to count the amount of data I have in the file, then I malloc the buf array with the amount of data that was counted and read from the file and populate the buf array. Then the function returns the buf array.

The issue I am having is that for some reason my buf array is not being populated with the data from the the file. So the printf prints out an empty line in the buff function. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Start by checking each function you call to see if it returned an error. And use `fstat()` to get the file size. Plus you're allocating 4 or 8 times more memory than you need, though that's better than not enough.

Comment: I already have done that when I print the out the variable "end" it prints out the file size

Comment: Do you know what your file is containing? If it starts with zeros, nothing will be printed

Comment: The file cannot be larger than buf since im dynamically allocating the buf array with the value I get back from lseek

Comment: Yes, noticed that you have both `buf` and `buff`

Comment: my bad forgot to delete it

Comment: Also your allocation should be for `sizeof(char)` and not `sizeof(char*)`

Comment: Only read `end` bytes, not `end + 1`.   `buf[end+1]= '\0'; `--> `buf[end]= '\0';`.  Many other issues too.
`

Comment: Still dose not work when I try that

Comment: I have a question if I malloc an array to be of size 30 bytes but i dont populate it, when I want to print out the size of the array is it supposed to be 30 bytes even tho nothing is inside of it?

Comment: That worked thanks I understand know why it didnt  work good looks xing

Comment: @laxattack `sizeof(buf)` is always the size of a pointer, not the size that you allocated it to point to. It doesn't matter if you populate it.

Answer (score 0):

It prints an empty value because you are doing this

1. Moving the file ponter to the end of the file with the *lseek* function, and memorizeing it to end variable.
2. Reading into buff variable from the file **starting from the file pointer moved** at the end of the file.

You are trying to read on a file that starts at its end, its normal that it is not returning anything on buff.

Try thys:

```
char *buff(const char *path){
 int end = 0; char * buf; int f_write = open(path,O_RDONLY); 
 end = lseek(f_write,0,SEEK_END);
 //now you have to move the file pointer back to the start of the file
 lseek(f_write,0,SEEK_SET);
 buf =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*(end+1));
 read(f_write,buf,end+1); close(f_write);
 //EDIT
 buf[end]= '\0'; printf("%s\n",buf);
}
```

Let me know if this solved :)

Comment: `buf[end+1]= '\0'` writes outside the allocated memory (if the allocation was right sized, which it is not).  Review `sizeof(char*)*(end+1)` and `buf[end+1]`.